# Помгите понять ошибку UnboundLocalError: local variable 'texture_v' referenced before assignment?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
from settings import *
from map import world_map


def mapping(a, b):
    return (a // TILE) * TILE, (b // TILE) * TILE


def ray_casting(sc, player_pos, player_angle,textures):
    ox, oy = player_pos
    xm, ym = mapping(ox, oy)
    cur_angle = player_angle - HALF_FOV
    for ray in range(NUM_RAYS):
        sin_a = math.sin(cur_angle)
        cos_a = math.cos(cur_angle)
        sin_a = sin_a if sin_a else 0.000001
        cos_a = cos_a if cos_a else 0.000001

    # verticals
    x, dx = (xm + TILE, 1) if cos_a >= 0 else (xm, -1)
    for i in range(0, WIDTH, TILE):
        depth_v = (x - ox) / cos_a
        yv = oy + depth_v * sin_a
        tile_v = mapping(x + dx , yv)
        if tile_v in world_map:
            texture_v = world_map[tile_v]
            break
        x += dx * TILE

    # horizontals
    y, dy = (ym + TILE, 1) if sin_a >= 0 else (ym, -1)
    for i in range(0, HEIGHT, TILE):
        depth_h = (y - oy) / sin_a
        xh = ox + depth_h * cos_a
        tile_h = mapping(xh , y + dy)
        if tile_h in world_map:
            texture_h = world_map[tile_h]
            break
        y += dy * TILE

    # projection
    depth, offset, texture= (depth_v,yv , texture_v) if depth_v < depth_h else (depth_h , xh, texture_h)
    offset = int(offset) % TILE
    depth *= math.cos(player_angle - cur_angle)
    depth =  max(depth , 0.00001)
    proj_height = min(int(PROJ_COEFF / depth),2 * HEIGHT)

    wall_column = texture[textures].subsurface(offset * TEXTURE_SCALE, 0, TEXTURE_SCALE, TEXTURE_HEIGHT)
    wall_column = pygame.transform.scale(wall_column, (SCALE, proj_height))
    sc.blit(wall_column, (ray * SCALE, HALF_HEIGHT - proj_height // 2))

    cur_angle += DELTA_ANGLE
```

Ошибка:

> File "F:\Python\KolfBloodC\raycasting.py", line 43, in ray_casting
> depth, offset, texture= (depth_v,yv , texture_v) if depth_v < depth_h else (depth_h , xh, texture_h) UnboundLocalError: local
> variable 'texture_v' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

Значит у вас условие `if tile_v in world_map:` ни разу не сработало, переменная `texture_v` осталась не инициализированной. После чего вы попытались взять значение этой переменной - и получили ошибку.

Вы либо должны задать в начале кода переменной `texture_v` некое "значение по умолчанию", либо, если такое поведение (`if` не сработал) - это нештатная ситуация, то нужно разбираться с кодом (и/или с данными), почему так произошло, а не пытаться просто обойти ошибку. Ошибка - это признак того, что ваш код работает не так, как вами задумано и в первую очередь надо разбираться именно с этим - почему он работает не так, как ожидалось.

Comment: кхм я не очень понимаю умные слова , если вы знаете как решить эту проблему могли бы вы код изменить?

Comment: @allahgator3000 Добавил ещё слов в ответ. Вам просто нужно разобраться - нормальное ли это поведение или у вас `if` должен был сработать. Если должен был - вам нужно разбираться, почему он не сработал (в данных что-то не то, например). Если не должен - задайте какое-нибудь значение по-умолчанию для этой переменной.

Comment: я уже разобрался в этой проблеме , надо было там кое-что поменять в настройках карты